# why log4j is not showing error messages in logs in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat7, log4j

If I get any exception in the application it is shown on the eclipse console. But the exception is not shown in the log file located in the tomcat logs folder. Is there anything that I am missing here?

Below is my full log4j file.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!-- Document : log4j.xml Created on : Feb 23, 2012, 9:30 AM Author : meshash 
        Description: Purpose of the document follows. -->

    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

        <!-- ====================================================================== -->
        <!-- A P P E N D E R S -->
        <!-- ====================================================================== -->

        <!-- console -->
        <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
                <param name="ConversionPattern"
                    value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} *%-5p* %c{1}: %M - %m - (%F, line %L)%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
            <!--  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />  -->
            <param name="File"
                value="C:/DEV_HOME/server/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/logs/headcount.log" />
            <param name="Append" value="true" />
            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
            <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern"
                    value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} *%-5p* %c{1}: %m (%F, line %L)%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <!-- ====================================================================== -->
        <!-- L O G G E R S -->
        <!-- ====================================================================== -->

        <category name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <priority value="debug" />
        </category>

        <root>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
        </root>

    </log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should post the code for print exception stacktrace.
Check if you are using `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `Logger.error("some message", e);`

Comment: e.printStackTrace(); will not be logged? what about the runtime exceptions like NullPointerException? Even NullPointerException is not logged to the log file.

Comment: e.printStackTrace(); will log to System.err instead of log4j, unless you redirect System.err using something like sysout-over-slf4j

Answer (score 0):

Save this file in the base directory,

src/com.yourproject.web... then:

src/log4j.xml

It works!!!